# Want to convert java struts 2 static code into dynamic

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have been assign to one struts2 project and its one of jsp contains more than 100 radio buttons and they have handled in statically not dynamically. As jsp contains 100 radio buttons so I am able to see the below list of radio buttons catches in actions with their getter and setter

- List selectRadioList001
- List selectRadioList002
- List selectRadioList003
- List selectRadioList004
- etc
- List selectRadioList100

I want to add these radio button in a list dynamically iterating through 1 to 100 something like below but when I try to access the variable like `"searchBoxSelectRadioList"+i` then it is pretending like a simple string. I want it to be like a List as shown above.

```
public class SelectRadioListPOJO {
    private List<TicketDesignUtil> selectRadioList;

    public List<TicketDesignUtil> getSelectRadioList() {
        return selectRadioList;
    }

    public void setSelectRadioList(List<TicketDesignUtil> selectRadioList) {
        this.selectRadioList = selectRadioList;
    } 
}
```

Action code:

```
List<SelectRadioListPOJO> selectRadioListPOJOList = new ArrayList<>();
SelectRadioListPOJO selectRadioListPOJO;

for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    selectRadioListPOJO = new  SelectRadioListPOJO();
    selectRadioListPOJO.setSelectRadioList("searchBoxSelectRadioList"+i);//   ERROR
    selectRadioListPOJOList.add(selectRadioListPOJO);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're asking.

You can't pass arbitrary values to methods; `setSelectRadioList` takes a list of `TicketDesignUtil`.

If your action doesn't have getters and setters for all of those radio buttons then you should resort to accessing the request parameters directly, for example, via [`ParameterAware`](http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/ParameterAware.html).

You would then access the radio button parameters by name from the injected parameter map.

Notes:

- It's not "pretending" to be a simple string, it *is* a simple string, because... well, because it is.
- Your `for` loop is wrong; I corrected it in your question to avoid others commenting on it. The POJO should be added to the POJOList inside the loop.
- Naming is funky; just call it `selectRadioListPojos`. Better yet, name it something domain-specific: variables should be *semantically* meaningful, not just a description of the class(es) involved.
- These shouldn't be static in the first place, but a map or array.